# Detect errors on web page with Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, html, error-detection

What is the best way to check our web applications for errors such as "duplicate attribute"?

My development team tends to use Firefox and Firebug for web development. We've noticed some errors creeping into the codebase, usually duplicate attributes such as:

```
<div id="MyDiv" class="hide" class="interestingDiv">
```

We see no errors in Firebug's console nor can see anyway to get Firebug to report that there are errors.

We have noticed that Firefox itself IS aware of these errors. By clicking on "View Page Source", Firefox renders the second class in red and has a tooltip of "Duplicate Attribute". However we have to hunt through the code ourselves looking for any errors highlighted in red.

Surely there is a better way than manually looking at the code? What tools should we be using?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 4):

Firefox automatically corrects HTML errors like duplicate attributes, i.e. it just ignores the second attribute. It doesn't expose this as error to its [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console).

Firebug just displays the error messages Firefox exposes via its APIs, it doesn't anaylize the HTML/CSS/JavaScript by itself. So as Firefox doesn't produce an error message for incorrect HTML, Firebug's *Console* panel doesn't display anything related to that.

Though Firefox offers another way to display HTML errors via is its source view. To get there just right-click into the page and choose *View Page Source* from the context menu. This view highlights duplicate attributes in red:

[image: Duplicate HTML attribute]

Other options you have are:

1. Use an HTML validator tool like the [*Html Validator* add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/html-validator/) or http://validator.w3.org/.
2. You may want to follow the Firefox [bug 878364](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=878364) asking for exposing HTML errors.

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. It seems a strange decision for Firefox to silently ignore the answer since isn't the reason for assigning a class to an element is that you want it to have some behaviour or appearance because of the element. So in your example, class "test" might make the section blue but class "hey" might allow it to be clickable. If these are ignored, then the application will not work as expected. 

Thanks for the buglink and other links too.

Comment: Note that Firefox is not the only browser that silently ignores duplicate attributes. All major browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera) do that. I checked the HTML5 standard, though I couldn't find a line declaring this behavior. It just says that there must not be two attributes with the same name on a tag. I suggest to follow the aforementioned bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The W3 html validator will look through your html and check for these kinds of errors:

http://validator.w3.org/

EDIT:
It looks like there's a Firefox add-on that validates HTML. I've never used it before but you might want to look into it:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Comment: That's great if we want to check each page individually, but I was hoping for something that plugged in to our workflow, such as something already part of Firebug. The devs already look at the Javascript console for errors, so ideally that's where issues with the page itself could be displayed (I think I have answered my own issue that they are looking at the JAVASCRIPT console, so why should that display HTML errors!)

Comment: This answer is a bit too broad. Can you please consider showing the an example of how the validator will help here.