# Does the browser have an HTML parser that I can access to get errors?

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing, html-parsing, gecko

I'm able to parse XML documents in the browser and get error messages using the following code:

```
// Internet Explorer
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
var hasError = (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0);

// Firefox, Opera, Webkit
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
var hasError = (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length > 0);
```

But I need to be able to parse an HTML document and check for errors.

Is there an HTML parser I can access in the same way as I'm accessing the XML parser?

**UPDATE:**

It looks like at least in Firefox I can attempt to create an HTML dom and parse the contents. But it doesn't seem to throw any error or return an error message no matter what I throw at it:

```
var text = "<html><body><label>test</labe></body></html>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
//var func = function (e) { console.log(e); };
//parser.attachEvent("InvalidStateError", func); // no attachEvent, no addEventListener
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
var hasError = (htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length > 0);
console.log("Has error: " + hasError); // also false. no errors ever.
console.log(htmlDoc);
```

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), this [page](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#parsing-and-serializing-nodes) and this [page](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#exception-domexception) helped me understand the DOMParser class more.

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript port of Tidy HTML such as https://github.com/lovasoa/tidy-html5. There is an error collection you can inspect on parse.

Comment: As far as “I can attempt to create an HTML dom and parse the contents. But it doesn't seem to throw any error or return an error message no matter what I throw at it”, that’s the nature of HTML parsers (at least the ones that [conform to the parsing algorithm in the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing)). They don’t throw and they don’t fail. Instead they will try to take whatever you throw at them and coerce it into a DOM. Even feeding, e.g., the empty string to an HTML parser will produce an HTML document.

Comment: The HTML Standard [does define something called a **parse error**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parse-error) but it is essentially an optional error-reporting function that conforming HTML parsers are not required to expose. Most parsers in browsers do not in fact expose it.

Comment: The parser that Firefox uses does in fact have the **parse error** error-reporting function built it, but I don’t know if there’s any way to expose it from Web content to your script. One way you can actually observe it is by using **View Source** for a document in Firefox; it will show the parse errors in red—and if you mouse over them, a tooltip shows the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425716/detect-errors-on-web-page-with-firebug is a related question. There’s also a somewhat-related [Report HTML parsing errors in the console](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=878364) open Mozilla bug.

Comment: @sideshowbarker man I want that bug fixed. people pull their hair out trying to get web layouts to work and here the browser is hiding all the reasons!! They said there are two renderers. The view source renderer includes the HTML error messages; the normal renderer ignores them. If we could set an option on the parser to return the HTML, CSS and JS errors that would be a game changer.

Comment: There’s not actually a bug here that needs fixing. What you’re encountering is expected behavior due to how HTML parsing is specified and how `DOMParser` and `parseFromString(…)` are specified. It’s  reasonable to argue the specs for all those should change, but in the mean time there are still ways to get parse errors programmatically from JavaScript—you just have to go outside what browser parsers have built-in natively. For one approach, [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932893/does-the-browser-have-an-html-parser-that-i-can-access-to-get-errors/32942169#32942169).

Comment: Yeah. The HTML parser is very forgiving. In fact I entered something like, "cNR#(cqrfjofjq0ef40438)*R$FHF@)" and it didn't throw any errors. I'm not proposing we change the spec just that we add an option to return the errors, warnings, etc. All the information a web developer would find useful. 

BTW I am outside of the browser in a way. I'm running a desktop application but I've been using the stage browser to create the DOMParser instance that I pass HTML data to. I then collect those errors and show them in the app to the user. But as we know HTML is not XML so it is not the same.